# What is the definition of mean in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, mean, dataframe

I have a data frame and would like to get a mean of the values from one of the columns. If I do:

```
print df['col_name'][0:1]
print df['col_name'][0:1].mean()
```

I get:

```
0    2
Name: col_name
2.0
```

If I do:

```
print df['col_name'][0:2]
print df['col_name'][0:2].mean()
```

I get:

```
0    2
1    1
Name: col_name
10.5
```

If I do:

```
print df['col_name'][0:3]
print df['col_name'][0:3].mean()
```

I get:

```
0    2
1    1
2    2
Name: col_name
70.6666666667
```

Comment: Might want to look http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html?highlight=mean#pandas.DataFrame.mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a column of `str` values, not `ints`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['2','1','2']})
for i in range(1,4):
    print(df['col'][0:i].mean())
```

yields

```
2.0
10.5
70.6666666667
```

while if the values are `ints`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[2,1,2]})
for i in range(1,4):
    print(df['col'][0:i].mean())
```

yields

```
2.0
1.5
1.66666666667
```

---

You can convert your column of `str`s to a column of `ints` with

```
df['col'] = df['col'].map(int)
```

But, of course, the best way to handle this is to make sure the DataFrame is constructed with the right (`int`) values in the first place.

Comment: Oh, good grief, because `10.5 == float("2"+"1")/2`.  I'd ruled that out without even looking to see because I'd assumed it would have raised.

Comment: Huh. I'm glad you figured out where those numbers were coming from. Hey, that's polymorphism for you! :)